# Вывод значений из результата запроса MySql

Tags: php, mysql

имеется таблица с полями `name`, `img`. 
Как сделать так, чтобы из переменной $im сделать массив из ссылок изображений и как потом вывести отдельную ссылку изображения из него?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($tab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $im = $tab['img'];
} echo $im[1];
```

Но оно выводит первый символ каждой ссылки изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$im = [];
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($tab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $im[] = $tab['img'];
}
```

Так по идее, должно работать, и каждую итерацию цикла, в массив `im` будет добавлять ссылка на новое изображения, в итоге получим массив ссылок.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @IvanGa отметьте пожалуйста вопрос как удовлитворяющий(галка под стрелочками), это сделает приятно мне, и поможет вам. Всегда рад помочь.